# How to give kubernetes node a host name that it can reach?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, centos, hostname

I am trying to set up a one master and one node k8s cluster; however, when joining my node to my cluster via:

```
kubeadm join 10.1.3.238:6443 --token 2xm3il.sqjbsq7ebn5yaz4x \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:7fb7e9ca3ee452928fd413bc3ecb4cb8bc50a99d52b73a39a5c758d240054c4e
```

it gives this output:

```
 [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "k8s-node1" could not be reached
 [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "k8s-node1": lookup k8s-node1 on 10.1.0.2:53: no such host
```

I have tried setting the hostname of the instances to k8s-master and k8s-node1 and I also added them to the etc/hosts file.  When I : `cat etc/hosts` on my master I get:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

ip-10-1-3-16 k8s-node1
ip-10-1-3-16 k8s-master
```

and when I : `cat etc/hosts` on my worker I get:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
ip-10-1-3-16 k8s-node1
ip-10-1-3-16 k8s-master
```

Comment: ip-10-1-3-16 is not valid IP. Try with 10.1.3.16

Comment: Are they in the same subnet? vpc? can you ping each other? it uses port 6443 is it open? can you telnet?

Comment: Set a DNS name for both hosts using [Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/route53/).  Don't try to use `/etc/hosts`, particularly when containers are involved: you'll have to replicate the manual hostname configuration to not just every host but also every container and it will rapidly become unmanageable.